# jest + typescript + es6 modules (yet again, 2019) - SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm still facing problems trying to use jest, typescript and es6 modules. My test are written in Typescript, I'm trying to import objects from js-file which uses es6 modules. To do that, I've followed [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel) and have the following in my babel.config.js, which is located in project root:

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            targets: {
                node: 'current'
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

};

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
  "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
  "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
  "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
  "jest": "^23.6.0",
  "rollup": "^1.1.2",
  "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
  "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.19.2",
  "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
  "ts-node": "^8.0.1",
  "typescript": "^3.2.4"
}
```

In jest.config.js I have the following:

```
module.exports = {
verbose: true,
transform: {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
},
testEnvironment: 'node',
testRegex: '/test/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|tsx)$',
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
};
```

And finally, I'm trying to import like this in my tests:

```
import {Dag, Directions} from "../dist/dag";
```

And here it says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

```
D:\devel\tomtom_dag\dist\dag.js:72
}();export { e as Directions, t as Action, n as Dag };
```

Can someone say what am I doing wrong or point to the project with similar config? And yes, I've googled this already for several hours and have tried solutions from [here](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/480), [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229) and have tried with [this](http://@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs) plugin - with the same result=(

**UPDATE:**
I've created a project to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/AntonPilyak/jest_typescript_es6
Also, I've noticed that I had forgot to mention that I was trying to use jest@23 version due to ts-jest can't work with the latest (gives a warning + I get an empty test suite). Maybe, my problems are coming out from that fact. But still, I'm unable to make a proper config: if I use the latest jest I get a warning + jest says that the test suite is empty and test is passing though it shouldn't.

Comment: I haven't used the exact stack you're using, but I've some some of the packages. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` makes sense because it's saying it's found TS in a JS file: `D:\devel\tomtom_dag\dist\dag.js:72` `}();export { *e as Directions, t as Action, n as Dag* };`. I can't see why that is from the info you've provided, but it's a lead you can follow.

Comment: @AndyJ, no, there is no TS in JS file, the other way around - I create bundle with Rollup where target format is 'esm' (ES6 modules), the bundler contains valid JS + file with types in the same folder. Then I'm trying to import objects from the bundle in my tests (which are, indeed, TS, but since I'm using ts-jest it should be fine.

Comment: I must be confised then. Why does the error message say there's TS in a JS file? The error says in file `dag.js`at line `72` there is `}();export { e as Directions, t as Action, n as Dag };`. `as` is not a JS keyword https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords but it is a TS keyword. https://github.com/zspitz/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/99ab9ee493fe13430b09a8a9fe33b7e5f066e55f/pages/Keywords.md The error is specifically about `export` which is a JS keyword, but I assume you're compiling to ES5, and `export` is ES6.

Comment: @AndyJ, I think that it is an outdated info, export {something as somethingElse} is a valid es2016 code, see here, for example: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from It is a proposal, but it has Current ECMAScript 2015 Modules section. Also, I've tried with debug version (non-uglified), it has no 'as' in export, but the result is the same.

Comment: So it is, my bad. Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: @AndyJ, NP, thanks for trying to help=)

Comment: FWIW I'm having a hard time recreating the issue.  Can you share a complete minimum codebase that fails with the error?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors: yes, I'll create a minimal project for reproducing the issue within 2-3 hours.

Comment: You have jest v^23.6.0 and babel-jest v^24.1.0, maybe configure jest using guide for [23.x](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/getting-started#using-babel) version?

Comment: @barbsan, but what exactly should I change? The config syntax seems to be the same. And, what would be more useful actually is to use the latest Jest somehow.

Comment: It seems like ts-jest team is going to release new version soon: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/pull/957. Hope that will help.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json, try adding "moduleResolution": "node" to compilerOptions. Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with ts-jest 24 + it appears to be a bug in my IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207553